# WWW:Facebook::API used in perl

Tags: facebook, perl

I am getting www:Facebook:api in perl and CPAN

error while using the Use of uninitialized value within %field in hash element at /usr/share/perl5/WWW/Facebook/API/Auth.pm line 62.
i defined all keys

```
      #!/usr/bin/perl -w

     use strict;
     use warnings;
     use CGI;
     use WWW::Facebook::API;
     use WWW::Facebook::API::Auth;

     use HTTP::Request;
     use LWP;

     my $TMP    = $ENV{HOME}.'/tmp';

     my $facebook_api      = '--------';
     my $facebook_secret   = '-------';
     my $facebook_clientid = '--------';

     my $gmail_user        = '-------';
     my $gmail_password    = '--------';

     my $client = WWW::Facebook::API->new(

     desktop         => 1,
     api_version     => '1.0',
     api_key         => $facebook_api,
     secret          => $facebook_secret,
     throw_errors    => 1,     
     );

     $client->app_id($facebook_clientid);

     local $SIG{INT} = sub {
     print "Logging out of Facebookn";
     my $r = $client->auth->logout;
     exit(1);
      };

     my $token = $client->auth->create_token;
     print "$token \n";

     $client->auth->get_session($token);
     print "$client \n";
```

Answer (score 2):

WWW::Facebook::API doesn't look like it's been updated for a while. Line 62 of that file is:

```
$self->base->{ $field{$key} } = $resp->{$key};
```

The undefined value is the `$field{$key}` part. The `%field`hash is a hard-coded mapping between the names of Facebook API's known fields (i.e. the fields in the data Facebook returns to you) and the names which the module wants them to be called. It seems that Facebook has added some additional fields to its data, and the module has not been updated to deal with them.

Ultimately, this is just a warning; you can just ignore it if you like. If you want your script's output to be a bit tidier, you could change that line to:

```
$self->base->{ $field{$key} } = $resp->{$key} if defined $field{$key};
```

Comment: When i am running my code i am getting a 32 length alpha numeric encrypted auth token. how can i decrypt that and use as original auth token.

Comment: response =
{"error_code":100,"error_msg":"Invalid parameter","request_args":[{"key":"api_key","value":"getting 15 digit value"},{"key":"auth_token","value":"32 length alpha numeric key"},{"key":"call_id","value":"getting 15 digit decimal value"},{"key":"format","value":"JSON"},{"key":"method","value":"facebook.auth.getSession"},{"key":"v","value":"1.0"},{"key":"sig","value":"32 getting length key"}]} 
now not getting that  warning but still getting this error